# i want to keep my users logged in a laravel app even after long time

Tags: php, laravel

i have a laravel application (web and PWA), i want the user to be logged in, i have the remember me set automatically after user logged in, and my session time increased to a very long time but the users still gets logged out after i close my browser then open

```
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $customRememberMeTimeInMinutes = 2628000;  
 $rememberTokenCookieKey = Auth::getRecallerName();  
 Cookie::queue($rememberTokenCookieKey, Cookie::get($rememberTokenCookieKey), $customRememberMeTimeInMinutes);  
 $request->session()->regenerate();  
 $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);  
 return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())  
     ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried the login via remembered?
```
if (Auth::viaRemember()) {
    // code to proceed
}
```

Comment: nope, how do i do that?

Comment: Please, update your post with the login post method. It will help us out how to answer your question.

Comment: @Guerrato , what do you mean, and how do i do it?

Comment: Add your written Laravel authentication method into your question, so we will be able to help you out. 
Be sure you removed sensitive data before paste it here